# (React) Header and Footer are not at the same width produces a Scroll X - How to remove the axe X scroll and fix the width of the footer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a basic landing page with Header , Content and Footer , however the Header is smaller than the Footer (its width) and as a result the page has a Scroll along the X axe.

Here is the Code

https://9mjhi.csb.app/

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './styles.css';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />     
      <Footer>
        <span>&copy;</span> Some Footer goes here
      </Footer>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Footer :**

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  style: {
    backgroundColor: "#484848",
    color: "white",
    borderTop: "1px solid #E7E7E7",
    textAlign: "center",
    padding: "20px",
    position: "fixed",
    left: "0",
    bottom: "0",
    height: "60px",
    width: "100vw"
  },
  phantom: {
    display: "block",
    padding: "20px",
    height: "60px",
    width: "100vw"
  }
}));

function Footer({ children }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.phantom} />
      <div className={classes.style}>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Footer;
```

**Header :**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  container: {
    display: "flex",
    width: "100vw",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    alignItems: "flex-start",
    backgroundColor: "lightblue"
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120
  },
  root: {
    width: "100%"
    // maxWidth: 500,
  },
  col: {
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#fff",
    height: "150px"
  },
  error: {
    color: "red",
    fontSize: "12px"
  }
}));

const Header = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <>
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <div className={classes.col}>.... Something goes here</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

How can we fix the scroll on the X axe and the width of the footer (match it to the header) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS property overflow!

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp

```
.body {
overflow-x:hidden
}
```

edit: this css prop must wrap the whole page

Comment: Sorry use body selector, it needs to wrap the whole page!

Answer (score 0):

- **makeStyles-style-7** has fixed positioning and left is zero but you have a 8px margin for your body that's why **makeStyles-container-2**
  also has 8px margin left.
- **makeStyles-phantom-8** is overflowing because of the padding.
  check [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Try this:

```
.body {
  margin: 0px;
}
.makeStyles-phantom-8 {    
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```